# Python scraper not writing correctly to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm new to python and programming, but having a bit of a problem with my project. I'm trying to scrape a website for data and save it in a csv. I works but when I'm writing the "lst" list to "Image URL" and "Image Featured" the brackets "[" and "]" and
'"' also get written to the csv file. is there a way to remove this? I know it´s because the "lst" list cointains other list with the urls.

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

today = date.today()

source = requests.get('https://www.meklarin.fo/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\Kassin.fo\kassin\blog\management\commands\test.csv')
print(df.to_string())
                        
original_house_title_list = []
original_house_link_list = []
house_titles_list = []
house_asking_price_list = []
house_current_bid_price_list = []
house_link_list = []
product = 'product'
current_date = today.strftime("%m.%d.%y")
house_image_list = []
house_location_list = []
lst = []
lst1 = []

house_info_list = []
house_final_info = []
list_convert = []

for house_link in soup.find_all('a', class_='house-air-content'):
                house_link = house_link.get('href')
                house_link_list.append(house_link.strip())
                print(house_link.strip())

for house_link in house_link_list:
    if house_link in original_house_link_list:
        continue
    else:
        source = requests.get(house_link).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

        for house_titles in soup.find_all('div', class_='ogn-base-info'):
            house_title = house_titles.h1.text
            house_titles_list.append(house_title)
            #print(house_title)

        for house__asking_price in soup.find_all('div', class_='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 house-ask-price house-price-column'):
                house_asking_price = house__asking_price.text
                house_asking_price = str(house_asking_price)
                house_asking_price = house_asking_price.removeprefix('Prísuppskotkr.')
                house_asking_price = house_asking_price.replace('.','')
                house_asking_price_list.append(house_asking_price.strip())
                #print(house_asking_price.strip())

        for house__current_bid_price in soup.find_all('div', class_='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 house-bid-price house-price-column'):
                house_current_bid_price = house__current_bid_price.h3.text
                house_current_bid_price = str(house_current_bid_price)
                house_current_bid_price = house_current_bid_price.replace('.','')
                house_current_bid_price = house_current_bid_price.replace('kr','')                        
                house_current_bid_price_list.append(house_current_bid_price.strip())
                print(house_current_bid_price.strip())

        for house_all_images in soup.find_all('a'):
            if 'https://www.meklarin.fo/wp-content/uploads' in str(house_all_images):
                house_all_images = house_all_images.get('href')
                house_image_list.append(house_all_images)
                #print(house_all_images)
            else:
                continue
        lst.append(house_image_list)
        lst1.append(lst)
        house_image_list=[]
        
        for house_build_year in soup.find_all('div', class_='house-info-box-value'):
                if 'Trýst her' in str(house_build_year):
                    continue
                else:
                    print(house_build_year.text)

        for house_info in soup.find_all('div', class_='house-desc-comp'):
                house_info = house_info.text
                house_info = str(house_info)
                house_info = house_info.replace('Upplýsingar um bústaðin','')
                house_info_list.append(house_info)
                #print(house_info)
        house_final_info.append(house_info)
        house_info_list = []


dict = {'Title': house_titles_list, 'Content': house_final_info, 'Date':current_date, 'Post Type': product, 'Price': house_asking_price_list, 'Regular Price': house_asking_price_list, 'Sale Price':house_asking_price_list, 'Stock Status': 'instock', 'Image URL': lst, 'Image Title': house_titles_list, 'Image Featured': lst} 

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df.to_csv('test.csv')

print(len(house_titles_list))
print(len(house_asking_price_list))
print(len(lst))
print(len(house_final_info))
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove the list in the cell for (example) Image URL, before writing to the file, try:

```
df['Image URL'] = [','.join(map(str, i)) for i in df['Image URL']]
```

The line above can be copied and `Image URL` above can be changed to `Image Featured` to clean up the list in the other column.

Comment: i think the above comment will solve your query. also try to post either image or text of what the problem is occuring. for example in your case, the text which is typed into csv file along with  [ ] " .